# Error in FUN(left, right) using cooccur package

Tags: r

I am trying to use the cooccur package in R and was wondering if anyone has used this package or why I receive the error:

```
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Here is a snippet of the .csv file I am using if that is of any use. The first column currently doesn't have a header because I've been trying different things to make it work.

```
,bL,bD,eC,eH,eL,eT
NLA12AL101,1,1,0,0,0,1
NLA12AL102,0,1,0,0,0,0
NLA12AL104,1,1,0,0,0,0
NLA12AL105,0,0,0,0,0,1
NLA12AL112,1,0,0,0,0,0
NLA12AL113,1,1,0,0,0,0
NLA12ALR03,1,0,0,0,0,1
NLA12ALR05,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

I am not sure if I am loading the file in wrong or not but here is the code:

```
mydata <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Tom\\Documents\\bosmina.csv", 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And here is the code I used for cooccur:

```
cooccur.mydata <- cooccur(mat = mydata, type = "site_spp", thresh = TRUE, 
spp_names = TRUE)
```

I am new to R and I have found similar questions on Stack Overflow but I still can't figure out what exactly this error means. I apologize if this is a real simple question, but I am trying to figure this program out on my own. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of cooccur. Thank you for your interest in the package. Once you read in your data, you need to move the row names into the row.names so that they are not treated as data. If your row names are in a column called rnames, then one way would be row.names(mydata) <- mydata$rnames; mydata$rnames <- NULL. It looks like this is the only issue, but if something else comes up let me know. You can use maintainer("cooccur") to get my email. Dan Griffith

Comment: PS the error means that cooccur is trying to analyze non-numeric data. i.e., the text for the row names.